# Avoid Automatic Make Targets in Eclipse environment

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, configure, yocto

Eclipse's Auto generate Make Targets and delete make targets previously created from projects.

How to avoid this behaviour while making future builds in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can go to **Project properties** -> **C/C++ Build** and uncheck "**Generate Makefiles automatically**"

Comment: It is uncheck ... I guess that this option avoid the generation of makefile file, not make targets